# Is admin database cached in memory by mongoses in sharded mongodb cluster?

Tags: mongodb

If we store the app data permanently inside admin database is it more likely to be kept in memory cached by the mongoses and faster for queries considering mongoses keep most of CSRS config servers data cached in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongoses do not retrieve the entire admin database, store it in a cache of some kind and then query the local copy. They retrieve individual *documents* from various collections for various purposes.

If there is application data on the config servers in the admin database, it wouldn't be used by mongoses for routing so it would, in my estimation, never be touched by whatever processes load the routing data.